# Array com informações de um banco de dados

Tags: php, array

Estou iniciando um sistema de envio de email para um cliente. Ele tem SMTP da locaweb e eles tem uma API para envio de email. Até ai tudo bem consigo enviar os emails usando a api deles, mas me deparei com um dúvida que não estou conseguindo resolver.

É o seguinte: preciso montar um array com os email, mas os emails estão no banco de dados, então como posso fazer um loop de repetição dentro da array?

```php
$to = array(
    'email@email.com.br', 
    'email2@email.com.br',
    'email3@email.com.br',
    'emai4@email.com.br',
)
```

Tentei assim:

```php
$to = array(
    foreach ($query as $row):
        echo '"'. $row->email . '",' 
    endforeach;
)
```

Mas sem sucesso como posso resolver isso. Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: vc quer mandar um email para várias pessoas no campo `para/to` do email? qual biblioteca esta usando para enviar email?

Comment: Se você busca os dados com PDO e usa o FetchAssoc ele automaticamente trás um Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível criar um loop de repetição dentro de um array.
Você pode criar o array de emails usando o proprio retorno da query.
A cada linha de retorno você alimente o array de emails.

```
$sql = "sua query aqui";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arrayEmails[] = $row["campo_que_contem_o_email"];
}

echo $arrayEmails[0];
echo $arrayEmails[1];
echo $arrayEmails[n];
```

Comment: Obrigado fiz dessa forma deu certo